# How to change table (default) collation in MySQL WITHOUT converting the columns

Tags: mysql, collation

The usual way to change collation on a mysql table is:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What I want to do is change the tables default collation WITHOUT changing the existing colums collation. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tbl_name [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]` Just omit the `CONVERT TO` part and set the charset for the table. Existing columns will not be converted. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html

Comment: Grrr... It is not a dup.  This talks about the _default_ for a _table_.  The other talks about messed up characters (in spite of what the title says).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` has two different ways to change a table's character set. The one mentioned in the question is meant to convert all character based columns into the given charset.

Setting the tables `DEFAULT` character set will not change the character set of the existing columns.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
  [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
  [COLLATE collation_name]
```

Related doc entries:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html